# Rails action cable, Input doesn't get cleared after POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I had this code and was working fine, just notices that the 'event.keyCode' is depricated as VScode saying

```
consumer.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log(data.content)
    $('#comments').append('<strong>' + data.content[1] + ': ' + '</strong>' + data.content[0] + ' ' + data.content[2] + ' <hr class="comments-hr">' )
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});

var submit_messages;

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  submit_messages()
})

submit_messages = function (){
  $('#new_comment').on('keydown', function (event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
      $('#send_button').click()
      event.target.value = ''
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
}
```

so i chagnged it to

```
submit_messages = function (){
  $('#new_comment').on('keydown', function (event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      $('#send_button').trigger( "click" )
      event.target.value = ''
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
```

so the problem i face now with the both options above is that the input doesn't get cleared after i press the button or clear press enter

[image]

if use this

```
$('#comment_field').val('')
```

and press enter  i don't get the value at all but i do when i click the button

[image]

this is the model

```
    def self.post_comment(new_comment,ticket,user)
        ticket.comment.tap do |post_new_comment|
            post_new_comment.content << new_comment
            post_new_comment.username << user
            post_new_comment.sendtime << Time.now
                if post_new_comment.save
                    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'comments_channel', content: [new_comment, user, Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")]
                end
        end
    end
```

the input field

```
        <%= f.text_field :comment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write a Comment", id: "comment_field" if @ticket.status%>
```

and the button

```
    def submit_comment_button
        content_tag(:button, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary", id: "send_button") do
            content_tag(:i, class: "bi bi-arrow-right-square") do
            end
        end  
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found was to move

```
$('#comment_field').val('')
```

at `received(data)`

like that

```
  received(data) {
    console.log(data.content)
    $('#comments').append('<strong>' + data.content[1] + ': ' + '</strong>' + data.content[0] + ' ' + data.content[2] + ' <hr class="comments-hr">' )
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $('#comment_field').val('')

  }
});

var submit_messages;

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  submit_messages()
})

submit_messages = function (){
  $('#new_comment').on('keydown', function (event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      $('#send_button').trigger( "click" )
      //$('#comment_field').val('')
      //event.target.value = ''
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
  
}
```

if someone could explain why i have to make that change and why it was working before i would be glad!